# Symfony2 Mapping 4 table Inner Join query to Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have 4 tables, the properties in the entities are all mapped accordingly. I'm trying to query for articles based on selected tags.

```
articles => id, title, author_id - NAMESPACE AppBundle/Enity/Article
tags => id, name - NAMESPACE AppBundle/Entity/Tag
article_tags => article_id, tag_id
authors=> id, name - NAMESPACE AppBundle/Entity/Author
```

I've figured out how to get all articles by which tags have the id's related to them in the article_tags table and filter by author id as well. In SQL my query looks like this. Tested and working.

```
SELECT 
    articles.title, articles.id, authors.name
FROM
    article_tags
INNER JOIN tags
    ON article_tags.tag_id = tags.id
INNER JOIN articles 
    ON article_tags.article_id = article.id
INNER JOIN authors
    ON authors.id = articles.author_id
WHERE
    tags.id IN (1,2)
```

I'm trying to build a query that represents the above sql. So far my understanding is that doctrine will automatically pick up the needed associations based on the ORM assertions in the entities. However I'm not certain how to bring the other entities into the query. This is what I have so far.

**my code in the article repo is:**

```
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ar')
            ->select('ar.title, ar.id, au.name')
            ->from('article_tags', 'at')
            ->innerJoin('tags', 't', 'WITH', 'at.tag_id = t.id')
            ->innerJoin('ar', 'WITH', 'at.article_id = ar.id')
            ->innerJoin('authors', 'au', 'WITH', 'au.id = ar.author_id')
            ->where('at.id IN (1,2)');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I have tried the above code with both the 'ON' and 'WITH' keywords.

**My error is:**
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'tags t WITH at.tag_id': Error: Class 'tags' is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing joins with Doctrine ORM, you shouldn't need to specify the join conditions as that should be in the metadata of your entities.

So in your instance you have articles related to tags and authors, and if you want the tags and authors along with your articles, your query should look something like:

```
// this is in the article repository I'm guessing?
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ar');
$qb->addSelect([ 't', 'au' ])
    ->join('ar.tags', 't')
    ->join('ar.authors', 'au')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('a.tags', ':tags'))
    ->setParameter('tags', [ 1, 2 ]);
```

So the two join statements are on properties of the entities, in this case `tags` and `authors`. Within your article entity you'll need to set these up as associations as per [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html). The metadata defines how articles relates to tags and authors and Doctrine will (usually) fill in the gaps. Your query looks like it's still thinking in SQL rather than entities and Doctrine (and DQL).

As a side note, the above isn't a great query to do as the number of rows returned will be equivalent to the number of tags and authors, you'd be better off do the query without the extra entities in the select, then grabbing the tags afterward (e.g. by doing `$article->getTags()`).